# Triangulation induces regular CW complex structure

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

If a topological set is triangulable, dose the triangulation map gives it the (regular) CW complex structure? From definitions, I see it seems to be, but I am not that sure, for may exist some strange examples.

Really, thanks for any help

Comment: A triangle is  homeomorphic to a disk, a $3$-dimensional simplex is homeomorphic to a $3$-dim ball etc.

Comment: Yes, in my understanding triangulation is very strong. So do you mean triangulation will induce a CW complex structure?

Comment: @lunzhang What is your definition of triangulation? If it is "homeomorphism with a simplicial complex", then the answer is yes (every simplicial complex has an obvious CW structure).

Comment: Yes, that is the definition plus some like locally finite condition. So triangulation and regular CW complex are equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent. A triangulation is a *special case* of a CW complex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You can see it as a consequence of Proposition 5.33 in Lee's book:

> Introduction to Topological Manifolds, 2nd ed. Grad. Texts in Math.,
>   Springer, 2011.

I quote the proposition:

> If $\mathcal{K}$ is a Euclidean simplicial complex, then the
>   collection consisting of the interiors of the simplices of
>   $\mathcal{K}$ is a regular CW decomposition of $|\mathcal{K}|$ (the
>   polyhedron associated to $\mathcal{K}$).